# The asymptotic upper bound of $E_Y \{ e^{-Y^2 + xY} \}$

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is the variable and $Y$ is an independent arbitrary positive real RV. It is easy to verify that 
$$
e^{-y^2 + xy} \leq e^{x^2/4}
$$
so that function $f(x)$ defined as
$$
f(x) = E_{Y}\{ e^{-Y^2 + xY} \} \leq e^{x^2/4}
$$ 
for any possible distribution of $Y$. I was wondering with $x \rightarrow \infty$, is there a tighter upper bound of it? I think there might be something like $e^{ax}$. Can anyone give a hint on any reference about the problem?

A slightly better solution:
given an $x >> 0$, function $$e^{-y^2 + xy}$$ is convex in $(0, \frac{x - \sqrt{2}}{2})$ and $(\frac{x + \sqrt{2}}{2}, \infty)$ and concave in $(\frac{x - \sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{x + \sqrt{2}}{2})$, so $f(x)$ (x >> 0) can be bounded as
$$
f(x) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-y^2 + xy} \text{d}F(y) = (\int_0^{\frac{x - \sqrt{2}}{2}} + \int_{\frac{x - \sqrt{2}}{2}}^{\frac{x + \sqrt{2}}{2}} + \int_{\frac{x + \sqrt{2}}{2}}^{\infty}) e^{-y^2 + xy} \text{d}F(y)
$$
$$
\leq e^{x^2/4 - 1/2} + e^{-E^2Y + x EY}
$$

Comment: For the constant r.v. $Y \equiv x/2$, equality is achieved, so how can there be a tighter bound without further conditions?

Comment: The distribution of $Y$ is fixed, while $x$ is an independent variable.

Comment: $f(x) = E_{Y}\{ e^{-Y^2 + xY} \} \leq E_{Y}\{ e^{xY} \} \le e^{ax}$ if $a$ is an upperbound on $Y$.  If $Y$ does not have an upperbound then you'd need more info on its distribution.